# How to lock/hide the code in HTA application using any code or software except VbsEdit?

Tags: vbscript, hta

Please don't tell me to use VbsEdit,it's not working.It just extracting.
Question: How to hide code or make it non-editable for others who are using this application by using code or any software?
I know there are few post regarding this but all answers are not upto mark or not working.
This is the reason i am posting it again.Please advise.

Comment: There is no way, open source is just the nature of HTML.

Comment: The only way I could conceive to do as you're asking (and it's only obfuscation) is to encode the VB portion of your HTA using screnc.exe. The following ScriptingGuy post details how this used to be done. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/03/09/how-can-i-encode-scripts-within-an-hta/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HTA you can use JAVASCRIPT to disable right click, F-Keys or Alt. 
By the way, it works for me when I call the page from a shortcut.

```
 <script language="javascript">
 document.onmousedown = chekkey;
 document.onkeypress = chekkey;
 document.onkeydown = chekkey;
 status = "Functionality Disable.(No righ-click, F-Keys or Alt)";

 function chekkey(e){
     if ((event.button == 2) || (event.keyCode == 123)||(event.altKey==true)||(event.ctrKey==true))
     {
      alert(status);
  if (event.altKey==true) {
       elementList[1].focus();
  }
      document.getElementById("add_the_Field_you_want_to_focus").focus();
      }  
  else if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||
           (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) ||
           (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122) ||(event.keyCode == 8))
     {
     return true; 
     }              
     return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **VbsEdit** is the answer. You must rename your HTA to **HTM** (e.g. MyScript.htm) and then use **Convert to Executable** in VbsEdit. If you don't rename, it just generates a self-extractor. When renamed to HTM, you get a proper Exe (The source code is NOT extracted to disk) and you can use VbsEdit's extensions for things like nice file open/save dialogs.

You must also have Visual Studio with C++ modules installed (e.g. Visual Studio Community 2022). VbsEdit uses Visual Studio to generate a unique, signable Exe that has its own replacement for MSHTA.exe embedded in it. This means the Exe will run on computers that have MSHTA blocked.

And, yes, you must pay $59 US for VbsEdit, but that's a **lifetime** license. That's dinner for two at a diner or maybe dinner for one at nice restaurant. That $59 will pay for itself in time-saved and problems-solved (e.g. via the use of the nice extensions) many times over.

Answer (score -1):

Disables context menu(right click) which includes a "view source" section
I think this might help a bit

```
<HTA:APPLICATION Contextmenu="no" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable right click menu, user can see the source code if you don't disable context menu.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION
    Contextmenu="no"
     />
```

> You can also obfuscate your script.
> VBScript:
> https://isvbscriptdead.com/vbs-obfuscator
> Javascript:
> https://obfuscator.io